# Synchronous beahviour of tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

Is there a way in tornado framework to setup callbacks synchronously.

For eg

```
print word

self.twitter_request(path= "/search",
    access_token=self.current_user["access_token"],
    callback=self.test,q=word,rpp="100")
```

And my test function is defined as

```
def test(self,response):
        print "Test"
```

In the above request, I have a set of 2 words which is being queried against the twitter api. However, the above request functions synchronously.

I get output as

Query1

Query2

Test

Test

However I want to output as

Query1

Test

Query2

Test

Any ideas how to tweak the above code to achieve what I am intending to do?

Comment: Don't think this way, when working with asynchronous framework. Nested callbacks will help you.

Comment: Can you give me a link to nested callback examples

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1tm6AQWH here is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have a list of queries executed in order, then you could use the `@gen.engine` approach to doing your handler ( http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html ).  Then you would structure your code something like this:

```
 @gen.engine
 def doit(self):
     for word in LIST_OF_STUFF:
         print word

         response = yield gen.Task(self.twitter_request, 
                                   path= "/search",
                                   access_token=self.current_user["access_token"],
                                   q=word,rpp="100")

         # do something with response.
```

Comment: actually twitter_request is a function (defined in TwitterMixin) which needs to have a callback function defined within the request.

Comment: gen.Task will take care of the callback= bits and just return you the data in response.

Answer (score 1):

This would block tornado - it's single-threaded, single-process. So doing so is a very bad idea.

However, you can simply restructure your code so *Query 2* is triggered in the callback of *Query 1*.

To do this without making your code less readable with nested callbacks have a look at [`tornado.gen`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html).

Comment: Oh actually I forgot to mention. The self.twitter_request is inside a for loop which is why I iterate over the queries and get the results, but the actual parsing of the results starts when the for loop has ended. That was pretty annoying to me

Comment: Your problem is that parsing starts after all queries executed?

Comment: Yes exactly. Infact not all queries. Since i can make only 350 twitter requests, I call about 300 requests and then I try to sleep. Its actually after these 300 requests are issued, they start executing